# Hyper V Guests are not performing as expxted

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I am experiencing very slow performance on a HyperV Guest that runs W2012R2.

The guest is used as an Application Server that runs an ERP application. The erp application is responding very slow on simple actions like opening a an inventory item form. It behaves like it executes the same copen form ommand twice.
The Database Server tho, which runs on different guest runs ok.

I have tried both enabled and disabled NUMA spanning.

In addition to the above , when NUMA spanning is disabled i have problems with memory assigned to VM's. It is like it does not recognizes the 32 GB but only the 16GB wich is per cpu socket.

This slow perfomance is compared to another installation that i have with almost the same configuration.

The Hyper V host runs on a Dell R720xd

```
*Chassis Model PowerEdge R720xd 
Processor 1
Processor Brand Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v2 @ 2.00GHz 
Processor Version Model 62 Stepping 4 
Voltage 1200 mV 
Processor 2
Processor Brand Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v2 @ 2.00GHz 
Processor Version Model 62 Stepping 4 
Voltage 1200 mV 
Memory
Total Installed Capacity 32768 MB 
Memory Available to the OS 32723 MB 
Total Maximum Capacity 1572864 MB 
Memory Array Count 1 
Memory Array 1
Location System Board or Motherboard 
Use System Memory 
Installed Capacity 32768 MB 
Maximum Capacity 1572864 MB 
Slots Available 24 
Slots Used 4 
ECC Type Multibit ECC 

BIOS Information

Manufacturer Dell Inc. 
Version 2.1.3 
Release Date 11/20/2013 
Software Profile
Operating System

Name Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2, Standard x64 Edition 
Version Version 6.3 (Build 9600) (x64) Server Full Installation*
```

---

The good performance installation runs on HyperV Host Dell T410

```
Chassis Model   PowerEdge T410
System Revision II
Processor Brand Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
Processor Version   Model 44 Stepping 2
Voltage 1200 mV
Memory  
Total Installed Capacity    32768 MB
Memory Available to the OS  32768 MB
Total Maximum Capacity  131072 MB
Memory Array Count  1
Memory Array 1  
Location    System Board or Motherboard
Use System Memory
Installed Capacity  32768 MB
Maximum Capacity    131072 MB
Slots Available 8
Slots Used  4
ECC Type    Multibit ECC
Name    Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise x64 Edition
Version Version 6.1 (Build 7601 : Service Pack 1) (x64) Server Full Installation
```

Comment: And did you do your homework? A baseline performance analysis from both - host and client - please. CPU usage, memory usage, DISC IO USAGE. We will not do your work for you - not if you refuse to even provide baseline information. I would bet your disc subsystem is overloaded like hell beacuse you tell nothing about that.

Comment: At first thank you for the edit. here are the links of the perf mon reports https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2391067/Guest.rar and the host https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2391067/Host.rar

Comment: The server is a new setup with 4 VM's there is not that much going on .

Comment: And you expect me to get a RAR and do your work? Whow. How much you pay for us doing it? Put an abstract into your question.

Comment: if you would take a look then you would see that there is no Disk IO usage as you have mentioned

Comment: On the other hand if my report is not well documented then i apologise and please close the post. I dont want to be any trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'll point out:  when you turn off NUMA, what you are saying is "only use the RAM that is directly connected to yourself" - so that's why you're only seeing half when you turn that off.

Otherwise, you gave a lot of information, but not the information we really need to help you with this.  I will say looking at your guest information, you do have a disk queue of anything over 1, which in Windows-land means you likely have an IO-type problem somewhere for that guest:

Current Disk Queue Length   _Total  0.23    0   7

When in doubt, for Windows troubleshooting start with disk, then RAM, then CPU when looking for a slowness culprit.  If you have more than one guest on the machine, those other guest(s) can cause problems even if the primary guest you're looking at is the only one where you see the issue.

With respect to different behavior between machines - is the same load across the board on both of them (both guest-wise and this specific application guest)?  And we don't have any storage information here, so can't really speak to that.

You need to look at individual disk/spindle/array-level performance for both guest and host first, you will likely find your answer there.